# Android Studio AVD Manager - setting environmental variable doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, environment-variables, avd-manager

Goal:
manage Android Virtual Devices (avd) using the (graphical) AVD manager shipped with Android Studio, but using a different storage folder.
Default folder: `/home/user1/.android/avd/`
Wanted folder: `/mnt/data/some/more/path/.android/avd`

According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables), this should work:
(Loaded in .bashrc)

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME='/mnt/data/some/more/path'
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME="${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/.android"
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME="${ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME}/avd"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT='/mnt/data/some/more/path/Sdk'
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools"
```

This works indeed on the command line:

```
$ emulator -list-avds
Nexus_5X_API_29_x86
Pixel_2_API_28
```

and running `emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28` works fine too.

**However**, AVD manager shows me no devices and when I use the only visible button `+ Create Virtual Device...`, the new device will be created in the Default folder (`/home/user1/.android/avd`).

Worth mentioning (but I don't know if related): In settings>Tools>Terminal > And then looking at the list of Environment Variables, I cannot find eg. $ANDROID_SDK_HOME under 'Include system environment variables'.
But at the other side, when opening a terminal in Android Studio, they are available.

*Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug (and should I rapport it)?*

Thanks

Environment:
Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon
Android Studio 3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching some more, this bug is already reported:
https://issuetracker.google.com/152333601

Star this issue there if this bothers you too.

Comment: Just ran across this issue today.  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the path to "Edit Custom Properties" (gear bottom left android
   studio). Like so: `ANDROID_AVD_HOME=PATH_TO_FOLDER_HERE`
2. Restart Android Studio

Source: Comment #4 on this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78686872